# T-SQL: Simplify Select statement with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: t-sql

I have the following select SQL that does a basic select statement although it does include a calculated column:

```
    Select *
    From
    (
      Select *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                              (ORDER BY
                                CASE WHEN @sortBy = 0 THEN R.DateCreated End Desc,
                                CASE WHEN @sortBy = 1 THEN R.DateCreated end Asc,
                                CASE WHEN @sortBy = 2 THEN TotalVotes END Desc,
                                CASE WHEN @sortBy = 2 THEN R.TotalFoundNotUseful END Desc
                              ) AS RowNumber 

      From
      (
        Select *, (TotalFoundUseful + TotalFoundNotUseful) As TotalVotes
      From Reviews
      Where (DealID = @dealID) And (TotalAbuses < 10) And (Deleted = 0)
    ) As R
  ) As Rev
  Where RowNumber BETWEEN @startRecord AND @endRecord
```

If you look carefully, the SELECT statement itself is executed 3 times. I can't believe that this is necessary. Is there a way to reduce this to 2 select statements (or possibly even one). I don't actually need to return the RowNumber. It is only used for selecting rows within a certain range.

Comment: The `SELECT` isn't executed three times. SQL Server will expand out the derived table definitions.

Comment: The Reviews table is only hit once, on the innermost select, filtering and counting the total #records. The next outer select adds ordering and a row number to the first, and the outermost just returns the page of data. It seems quite efficient to me, given that any paging strategy would also need to know the total rows in the filter (before it is paged).

Comment: I guess what I believe is happening is that each time a Select statement is executed, SQL Server will iterate over all the records. So if I had 10 records on the inner most Select, the middle Select would also repeat 10 times in order to perform the sort. Then the whole thing gets done 10 more times for the most outer Select, which in effect results in 10x10x10 = 1000 iterations.

Comment: @androiddev, you shouldn't think of database as iterating over records, they work in sets of data not individual records unless you specifically use a cursor or while loop or correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with two by putting the rownumber in with the original select against reviews. You can't go to one if you want to have a WHERE clause on a windowing function like ROW_NUMBER.

You do have to write `TotalFoundUseful + TotalFoundNotUseful` twice but it will only be evaluated once so that doesn't effect performance.

I also wouldn't expect moving to two to have any effect on performance but you should test it.

```
Select *
    From
    (
  Select *, (TotalFoundUseful + TotalFoundNotUseful) As TotalVotes,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER
              (ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN @sortBy = 0 THEN DateCreated End Desc,
            CASE WHEN @sortBy = 1 THEN DateCreated end Asc,
            CASE WHEN @sortBy = 2 THEN TotalFoundUseful + TotalFoundNotUseful END Desc,
            CASE WHEN @sortBy = 2 THEN TotalFoundUseful END Desc
          ) AS RowNumber 
 From Reviews
     Where (DealID = @dealID) And (TotalAbuses < 10) And (Deleted = 0)

  ) As Rev
  Where RowNumber BETWEEN @startRecord AND @endRecord
```

Comment: This works great except for one problem I now discovered. If I have two records where TotalFoundUseful = 100 but one record has TotalFoundNotUseful = 5 and the other = 3, the record with 5 comes first followed by the one with 3. I want it the other way around. The one with 3 should come first. I modified the last CASE statement to be TotalFoundNotUseful END ASC, but this didn't work.

Comment: So when `@Sortby  = 2` it sorts first by totalvotes and then by TotalFoundUseful. What are the total votes for problem data that you're working with?